# Eclipse Split string in lines and remove leading and trailing spaces

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to remove spaces from a string where string is divided in lines. After splitting into lines, leading and trailing spaces need to be removed. Where numbers of lines are not fixed.

What I am trying is

```
      String[] lines = Imgdata.split("\r\n|\r\n");

      String firstLine = lines[0].trim();
      String firstLine = lines[1].trim();
```

Here i am able to do for two lines. What can be done where number of lines are not fixed. It can be 4 or 5 or 6.

Comment: You need to use two backslashes while mentioning your regular expressions in Java. So use: `Imgdata.split("\\r?\\n");` as it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
 String lines[] = String.split("\\r|\\n");
```

instead. and then perform actions as you are currently doing them. :)

Comment: Can u please explain what this regular expresion is actually doing.      ("\\r?\n")

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, if the number of elements in the array is unknown.
This will trim every string in your array.
Note: the original, untrimmed strings will be lost.

```
String[] lines = Imgdata.split("\r\n|\r\n");

for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    lines[i] = lines[i].trim();
```